# FlexScroll and IFRAMES

Tags: javascript, html, css

Hey, I was wondering whether there is a way to use FlexScroll (JavaScript custom image based scrollbars) with IFRAMES instead of the DIVS.

Yes, I know scrollable DIVS are better than IFRAMES. This is my clients requirement though.

Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that FlexScroll cannot work with IFRAMES as an IFRAME's scrollbars are created within the browser itself.

:(